# Can't pair Android with Windows 7 via Bluetooth

Tags: windows-7, android, bluetooth

I can't pair my Android phone with my Windows 7 x64.

If I try to start the pairing in Android, after some time it says "Coudn't pair with PC because of an incorrect PIN or passkey", but I didn't even type one.

And when I try to pair starting on Windows 7, after I select my Android device, I get this window on Windows:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a145W.png]

But at the same time a popup opens on Android asking for a passkey (what should happen after I select the first option on Windows, I guess).

I tried '0000' and '1234', without success.

When I select the first option on Windows, right after it says "Adding this device to this computer failed... because of an authentication error". It doesn't even show a passkey. At the same time, pairing on Android is aborted.

When I select the second option, the same thing happens.

Whe I select the third option, Windows adds the phone, but only as a generic device. It does not appear as paired on Android, and I can't send files from Windows to Android.

Comment: Is transferring via the microSD card an option? Or using a USB cable?  It's a little less convenient, but a little more likely to get the job done.

Comment: Yes, it is. But since my laptop has a built-in bluetooth adapter, I don't want to carry around the USB cable.

Comment: Good point -- how about the MicroSD card? If don't use your SD reader much you could generally leave in a Micro SD to SD Adapter in the slot, and plug the microSD in and out.

Comment: It's difficult to remove the microSD card from my Android phone.

Comment: Not sure if it's a Windows problem or an Android problem (seems like a windows problem). I don't know if you happen to have a dualboot system, but if by chance you have do, you could try doing it from Linux and see what happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Windows 7 and Android. Then, on Android, I tapped "Search for devices", selected my laptop, and a popup appeared on Windows' notification area, showing a passkey and asking if it was the same shown on Android.

Then, on both Windows and Android, I clicked "Yes" and "Pair", and right after Windows instaled the bluetooth features.

It's done.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should just choose the first option, then type the code Windows gives you into your phone.

Comment: When I select the first option, Windows says "Adding this device to this computer failed... because of an authentication error". It doesn't even show a passkey. At the same time, pairing on Android is aborted.

Comment: Could you update your question to detail what happens when you choose each option?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's updated now.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Bluetooth obviously isn't working, try using [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) instead. It uses Wifi and is extremely versatile (it should be able to do everything you needed and more).

As long as your laptop and your phone are on the same wifi network it should work...

The only drawback I can think of is that if you're on a public wifi network it will be a little less secure.

Read [this great write-up](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/airdroid-send-sms-share-links-transfer-files-android-21/) from MakeUseOf before you download the app, it'll explain everything.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I've been using a more lightweight alternative: WiFi File Transfer. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: @GutierrezPS If it worked, you can add it as an answer yourself and then mark it as resolved after two days (that way it'll stay out of the unanswered questions queue)